# Separating jquery events from same classname elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a scrollable list of items with two buttons: up and down. My goal is to show a single item whenever I click on any of the two buttons.
I'm using jQuery event `slideUp()` but whenever I click on the button all the list items slides up. I couldn't separate the event for each item. Help?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){      
       $(".bott").click( function() {
           $(".item").slideUp();  
        });
    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    
        <title>TEST</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <script src="js/menuscroll.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
     
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
      
       <li class="nav-item"> Home </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> About </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> Services </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> Contact </li>
    
      </ul>
     </div>   
    
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
       <div class="scroll-bottom">
          <button  type="button" class="bott btn-block">DOWN</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-top">
          <button type="button" class="bott2 btn-block" >UP</button>
        </div>
       <ul class="menu">     
      
         <li class="item">A</li>
         <li class="item">B</li>
         <li class="item">C</li>
         <li class="item">D</li>
         <li class="item">E</li>
         <li class="item">F</li>
         <li class="item">G</li>
         <li class="item">H</li>
         <li class="item">I</li>
         <li class="item">J</li>     
      
       </ul>
      </div> 
       <div class="paddles">        
     </div>
     </div>    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a counter to track which item you are sliding up or down. Check the following sample and do the same for the `sideDown()`(`counter--` on sliceDown()).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 1;
    $(".bott").click( function() {
       $(".item:nth-child(" + counter + ")").slideUp(); 
       counter++;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    
        <title>TEST</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <script src="js/menuscroll.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
     
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
      
       <li class="nav-item"> Home </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> About </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> Services </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> Contact </li>
    
      </ul>
     </div>   
    
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
       <div class="scroll-bottom">
          <button  type="button" class="bott btn-block">DOWN</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-top">
          <button type="button" class="bott2 btn-block" >UP</button>
        </div>
       <ul class="menu">     
      
         <li class="item">A</li>
         <li class="item">B</li>
         <li class="item">C</li>
         <li class="item">D</li>
         <li class="item">E</li>
         <li class="item">F</li>
         <li class="item">G</li>
         <li class="item">H</li>
         <li class="item">I</li>
         <li class="item">J</li>     
      
       </ul>
      </div> 
       <div class="paddles">        
     </div>
     </div>    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $(".bott").click( function() {
        $(".item:eq("+i+")").slideUp();
        i++;
    });
    $(".bott2").click( function() {
        i--;
        $(".item:eq("+i+")").slideDown();
    });
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    
        <title>TEST</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <script src="js/menuscroll.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
     
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
      
       <li class="nav-item"> Home </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> About </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> Services </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> Contact </li>
    
      </ul>
     </div>   
    
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
       <div class="scroll-bottom">
          <button  type="button" class="bott btn-block">DOWN</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-top">
          <button type="button" class="bott2 btn-block" >UP</button>
        </div>
       <ul class="menu">     
      
         <li class="item">A</li>
         <li class="item">B</li>
         <li class="item">C</li>
         <li class="item">D</li>
         <li class="item">E</li>
         <li class="item">F</li>
         <li class="item">G</li>
         <li class="item">H</li>
         <li class="item">I</li>
         <li class="item">J</li>     
      
       </ul>
      </div> 
       <div class="paddles">        
     </div>
     </div>    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works but i have to click on the first button first then continue sliding the items up with the second button. i want to use one button for sliding up and the other for sliding down. thank you

Comment: @Glory, check my updated answer. Its working perfectly now.

Comment: i want the first button to slide the whole list items separately.

Comment: Opps sorry. My bad, I missed one update before I saved the answer.
@Glory, please check the code now. I updated it again.